# R with Java, can path be made robust?

Tags: java, r

Can anyone tell me that I want to upload the application created by me in jsp on my website:

I simply want to avoid these things ie:

1. thing of writing the path i.e this R path on system.

   ```
   caller.setRscriptExecutable("C:\\R\\R-3.0.1\\bin\\i386\\Rscript");
   ```
2. The need to install R, I know these things seams impossible but it is to be done by me.

Can I bind it in any way, as the path is to be changed and R is to be installed every time the work is shifted from one system to another.

I'll using the appropriate library, but I don't want a code which wants R to be installed on the system as if R is uninstalled and installed again the path always need to be changed. I don't want this. Please tell me is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you include the files you need and then use a relative directory like this:

C:\application\app.exe
C:\application\libary\files-here

And access it like: caller.setRscriptExecuteable("\libary\files-here");

Comment: still C:\application\app.exe willbe there, or I'm not understanding what you're trying to explain me

Comment: Well i assume your application get's installed in a directory right? So by using a subdirectory within that directory you only be needing a relative path.

Comment: yes, for example my applicatiopn installs at "C:\\R\\R-3.0.1\\bin\\i386\\Rscript" and I used the same in my code...So how can I take a relative path?..read my question again...I want to avoid this thing.....my files will be kept in APache folder and I'm not understanding

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to include R inside your jar and extract in on the fly into a temporary directory.

A better way is using JRI, a Java/R interface.

Comment: ok thanks @ooxi, can you explain me in detail...or JRI will work for it..will it solve that issue of making code robust enoght to avoid installing R etc

Comment: If you go down the road of using JRI than this will be the most robust version, since it is platform independend. What build system do you use?

Comment: Netbeans IDE, Windows7 32bit, Jdk 1.7